# CRM 2013 - plugin executing at wrong time

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a plugin for the entity Contacts, however when a lead is set to "Qualify" and create new account and contact is selected, my plugin is firing which is causing a error message to appear

Within my plugin I did include the following

```
if (entity.LogicalName == "contact")
```

Which I believed would stop this from happening

Does anyone have any suggestions / recommendations of action to take to prevent this, as switching my Contact plugin to only execute on Update isn't an option

Comment: what is the error? You plugin must be registered on `Create` message. with lead you are selection create new account and contact. It creates a new contact which triggers the plugin.

Comment: The error is - The given key is does not exist in the current context, its because the plugin requires information that is only relevant on the contact entity not issue

Comment: If you don't want to run plugin in this case, I would suggest you to check context depth in your plugin. Only run your code if depth = 1.

Comment: Hi @Scorpion I ran the code if depth == 1 but on the Lead entity it was still trying to run, so i tried > 1 and that stopped it running on Lead but also on contact, any further suggestions?

Comment: debug the plugin to check which key is missing from context. Put that code in condition if possible. `if (entity.Contains("keyName")) { //DO THIS }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are getting an error `The given key is does not exist in the current context`. I would recommend you to debug the plugin to check which key is missing and put that code in if condition if its possible in your scenario.

```cs
if(!entity.Contains("keyName"))
{
     entity.AddAttibute("keyname");
}
```

Or you can check if originatingleadid is not null. If Messagename is `Create` and `originatingleadid` have value then contact is created from lead.

```cs
If (context.MessageName.ToLower() == "create" 
    && entity.Contains("originatingleadid") && entity["originatingleadid"] != null)
{
    // Do Nothing
    return;
}
else
{
    // Run your plugin code
}
```